# Grand Sum with distinct in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have  a table in which has duplicate values. by eliminating these values I want sum of distinct values. but without group by.

My table

```
--------------------------------------
ID           City          collection
---------------------------------------
1            xyz             5000
2            xyz             5000
3            abc             2000
4            pqr             3000
5            xyz             5000
6            pqr             3000
7            abc             2000
-----------------------------------
```

I want result of whole collection column but eliminate city name
ex. Result = 10000

not like

```
 xyz    15000
 abc    4000
 pqr    6000
```

or not like 25000

but result should be 10000 by eliminated

Comment: Result should be (xyz+abc+pqr)

Comment: Why without group by?

Comment: No matter if it is group by. but it should be grand total by eliminating duplicate city names.

Comment: Then remove that from your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `Distinct` combinations of City and Collection first and then do the `SUM`

```
select SUM(Collection) as Collection
from 
(
  select distinct City, Collection
  from table
) data
```

Comment: you can do this in one line SUM(DISTINCT [collection]), no need to do this as separate operations

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(collection) as output
from
(
    select collection, row_number() over(partition by city order by collection) as RN
    from yourtable
) as inside
where RN=1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the sum of the distinct values of the collections column without the city name (I assume this is what you want from your statement "but eliminate city name") then simply run this:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT [collection]) FROM tableName
```

This will return the value 10000 like you are after.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote anyone?  This code returns the answer the OP was looking for, is technically correct and most importantly requires the least typing :-)